# Netbeans + Checkstyle

Tags: netbeans, checkstyle

Does anyone have experience using checkstyle in netbeans 7? I have the plugin installed, and I have selected my configuration file but I'm not seeing any errors or the promised "annotation". Any suggestions? Is there something I need to do to get it to start working? I have the plugin activated in the plugins menu.

Answer (score 5):

Follow the directions in this [article](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/08/netbeans-7-and-software-quality.html). You might need to restart Netbeans after installing the plugins. Code violations should appear as annotations on the line number gutter.

You can then go to the tools/options/quality/checkstyle tab to set your custom checkstyle configuration files.

Not sure if this is important but make sure that your custom checkstyle.xml uses the Check Configuration 1.3 version.

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
```